# After resizing root and home partition it is stuck on emergency mode during boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, 18.04, uefi, gparted

I am running Kubuntu 18.04 LTS on my machine, it is fully dedicated and standalone with no other operating system on it.

Using an Ubuntu Live Disk and Gparted, I recently shrinked the size of my root partition from 160 GiB to only 60 GiB and increased the size of my Home directory partition which I had previously. The linux-swap partition which was about 10 GiB was sitting in between the root directory and the home directory. Which I have also shrinked to 4 GiB (as I have 12 GiB of RAM) and moved it in between boot partition mount and root partition mount.

So the partitioning is like below:

```
512 MB : /efi   
2 GB : /boot   
4 GB : /linux-swap   
60 GB : /root   
Everything else : /home
```

I haven't touched the efi and boot partition mount at all.

This is the error message as it shows below:
(I have also put a picture below for reference as it is an OCR version of the error message)

```
00440821 mce: [Hardware Error: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: ae00000000
40110a
0044086 ] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC O ADDR fef87700 MISC b8a0000086
0044089 ] mce: [Hardware Error: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1554998774 SOCKET O

APIC O microcode 25

10022361 Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)
1002260 ] Problem loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)
1559344 PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
1673021 ] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [_SB.PCIO.GFX0.DD02. BC
L. AE_NOT_FOUND 20180531 /psargs-330)

1673034 ] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed _SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP.DDO
2. BCL, AE_NOT_FOUND 20180531 /psparse-516)
1678519 ] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key

1679954 ] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "Journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
root@xen: # systemctl default
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type Journalctl -xb to view
system logs, "systemct1 reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
or press Control-D to continue):
```

Picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmtfY.jpg

I'm really locked out and used my phone to ask this question and this is my first community question ever. So please spare me for my mistakes. I only have my Laptop which I have messed up. A fast and easy solution is very much appreciated as I don't want to install Linux again and do everything from scratch (Exams are around the corner).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question has been asked before I think. Try disable secure boot from your UEFI Bios and clear the cert (if any) then rebooting.

Comment: Secure boot is disabled.
Doesn't work.

Comment: Boot using Live CD and drop to root prompt. Check that the store devices are present, e.g, /dev/sd* or nvme* and try mounting them manually on /mnt to see if they are all okay and your data are still present.

Comment: Yes I saw them! all my data is still there.

Comment: Can you post `parted --list <your drive>` and also content of `/etc/fstab` Just want to make sure if anything is statically configured to the device nod, it is still matching your current device setup. Add them to the end of your original question.

Comment: Let's close this question. I reinstalled my OS.

Comment: Sounds good. For the record, emergency mode is normally triggered when the home directory is missing or inaccessible. When you are able to reach this state it is most likely the rest of your system is running fine, and it just can't access your home.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.